# New version of Perl messed up @INC

Tags: perl

I'm using Linux Mint 17.
I've installed Perl version 5.20 over 5.18 version and now I have problems with installing new modules, because cpan is installing then into 5.20 folders, but @INC contains only:

```
(@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18
 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)
```

What is the best solution for this mess? Should I just add new 5.20 folders into @INC or is it too dirty way and I should somehow delete previous Perl version or even redo it all over again?

Tahnks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to deal with your current situation is, but for future reference, when installing a new Perl: Leave the system Perl well alone and use PerlBrew to the newer version in a home directory with local::lib.

Comment: You don't really need `perlbrew` or similar tools. They are convenient, but as brian d foy explains, it is easy to [build your own `perl`](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/10/compile-a-development-version-of-perl/). Also, this is not a programming question.

Comment: Check which version of perl you're actually running. You might find you've got two perls installed - one in `/usr/bin` and one in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: *"it is easy to build your own perl"* -- Yes, but only on a Linux-like system

Comment: @Borodin No, it is pretty straightforward to do so on both OS X and Windows as well. See my blog post [64-bit Perl 5.20.1 with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on Windows 8.1](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/11/64-bit-perl-5201-with-visual-studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin suggested, ***NEVER*** touch your system's Perl. Use [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/HAARG/local-lib-2.000015/lib/local/lib.pm) or [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

What you can do now is to use your distro's package manager to uninstall and install Perl, then leave it as it is and install perlbrew.

Comment: You can usually get away with dual install - leaving `/usr/bin/perl` as is, and installing `/usr/local/bin/perl`.